# Rubbing sounds when making sharp turns after getting the brakes replaced

Tags: brakes, wheels

Went to a auto shop to get all pads and front rotors replaced. Now my car is making a rubbing type noise at the wheels when making a sharp turn. Any ideas what this likely is?

Comment: Welcome to the site. First, check to ensure the lug nuts were tightened correctly. After that, look under the vehicle on either side to see if anything is sticking out and is obviously in a place to rub against the tire, like a brake line or some such. If that fails, take it back to the shop where you got it done and have them check it over ... really, it should be there responsibility as they did the work on it.

Comment: Does it happen when making a left turn, right turn or both? Which wheel is the noise coming from? In any case, take it back to the shop after following @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 good advice.

Answer (score 1):

From the information you've provided in your question, sounds like the brake backing plate may have been slightly bent (usually happens when the wheels are being re-installed) and when making a turn (left or right) you will hear the low grinding/rubbing noise.

I had the grinding/rubbing issue on my Tundra after getting the tires rotated and it ended up being the backing plate.

Take it back to the shop that performed the work, have them ride with you around the parking lot making a few turns (full left and full right) so that they can hear it; should be a relatively quick fix.

Hope this helps!